# How to search based on local time, accounting for timezones

Tags: search, time

I have a collection of shops with opening hours and want to know which of them are currently open.

The problem is that the shops are located all over the world.

This is what the find query looks like (I use SQL for example, but it doesn't matter):

```
SELECT shops.name  FROM shops 
LEFT JOIN shops_openHours ON shops_openHours.shopId=shop.id 
WHERE shops_openHours.day=[day of week] 
AND shops_openHours.openTime < [now time] AND  shops_openHours.closeTime > [now time]
```

When I store working time in local time I can't search because of timezones.

When I store working time in UTC I can't search because of daylight saving time.

Some sample records:

Query:

```
SELECT shops.name, shops_openHours.day day_of_week, 
shops_openHours.openTime, shops_openHours.closeTime FROM shops
LEFT JOIN shops_openHours ON shops_openHours.shopId=shop.id
```

Result:

```
name    day_of_week     openTime    closeTime   

shop1   'monday'        '09:00'     '18:00'
shop1   'tuesday'       '09:00'     '18:00'
shop2   'tuesday'       '10:00'     '19:00'
shop2   'tuesday'       '10:00'     '19:00'
```

Sample query (now it is monday 09:30):

```
SELECT shops.name  FROM shops LEFT JOIN shops_openHours ON shops_openHours.shopId=shop.id 
WHERE shops_openHours.day='monday' 
AND shops_openHours.openTime < '09:30' AND  shops_openHours.closeTime > '09:30'
```

result:

```
name

shop1
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample documents and what your expected output with an example?

Comment: By summer/winter you mean daylight saving time? That shouldn't be an issue when you store in UTC.. You may consider storing also the Timezone name in a separate field for some purposes

Comment: Yes, daylight saving time.   Local time adjusts  forward one hour close to the start of spring and adjusts backward in the autumn.  Local open/close time always will be the same, but UTC open/close  time will change by one hour.   How can I store time in UTC in that case?  I can periodically recalculate it, but it is ugly solution.

Comment: Solution isn't still founded. I can change database structure and queries, my structure is just example.  Store in UTC, store in local time, it doesn't matter. The problem is how to search by time all over the world. It is strange that nobody answers. What is the reason?